# Why error when printing Array of char with index

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char name[99];

int main(){
    int n = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        scanf("%s", &name[i]);
        //fflush(stdin); gets(&nama[i]);
    }

 for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    printf("Print %s", name[i]);
    }   

}
```

I want to asking why i got error when printing this code, but if i'm not using index such

```
for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        printf("Print %s", name);
        }
```

it can be printed without index.

Comment: it is giving me warning  no errors .. and segmentation fault during run time ..

Comment: Because `%s` expects the address of a NUL-terminated string, a `char*`, but you supply a `char`: `name[i]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

name is an array of individual characters, not strings.  Each scanf is reading into the one array at the next location.  In the loop where you print, you're putting individual characters into the pointer used by %s (note that char is an integral type in C, not a string of length 1 as in many languages).

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Two dimensional char array
char name[5][99];

int main(){
    int n = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        scanf("%s", name[i]); // Decay to char*
        //fflush(stdin); gets(&nama[i]);
    }

 for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    printf("Print %s", name[i]); // Decay to char*
    }   

}
```